# Do WCF Services have to have a MetaDataExchange endpoint for each service or can I have just one?

Tags: wcf, rest

If my WCF Configuration file has two services, lets says LoginService and RegistrationService, do they both have to have their own MetaDataExchange endpoint or can I just have one MetaDataExchange endpoint and keep it outside the service element:

```
<services>
<service name="a">
<endpoint binding="mexHttpBinding" />
</service>
<service name="b">
<endpoint binding="mexHttpBinding" />
</service>
<services>
```

Or is this valid as well:

```
<services>
<service name="a">
</service>
<service name="b">
</service>
<endpoint binding="mexHttpBinding" />
<services>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one.

When you add a service reference, it is for a service not for all services on a server.

Comment: When you say service reference, are you referring to the service endpoint?  If the MetaDataExchange endpoint is equal, why should I have to specify it twice?

Comment: The web config contains configuration for all services on the web site, in your case there are 2 services. One service could have 2 endpoints say http and https. 2 endpoints in one service would be 1 Metadataexchange endpoint.